# How to Add URLs to AngularJS After Initialization

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app, my config file runs setting up URLs. Then, after the config has been set up an API call is made that gets a bunch of elements that need specific URLs. How can I add a URL to my AngularJS app after it has been made?

Comment: I read this question several times and could not understand it. Perhaps with a little bit of code it would be easier to understand.

Comment: what does "add a URL" mean? are you meaning to ask how to add *routes* to your app?

Comment: How do add a URL to my site after config runs?

Comment: yeah how can i add a route after all the routes have been made during config

Comment: which router are you using? `ngRoute`? `uiRouter`? some other router?